# How to edit hosts with TextEdit on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, terminal, textedit, hosts

This line used to work
`sudo -b "/Applications/Textedit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit" /etc/hosts`

But on Yosemite, it does not work anymore.

Comment: This should work: "open -a TextEdit /etc/hosts"

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"' any longer? Any error messages?

Comment: @IronCraftMan it does not work: when trying to save I have a error message : "You do not have the permissions... to edit hosts"

Comment: @patrix Nothing happens!

Answer (score 1):

Yes I just tried your command and it exists with error code 132 (I don't know why).

You can still use this to open your hosts file `sudo open -t /etc/hosts`. It will open the TextEdit app, if you want to run it in the background you can add your `-b` in the command line.  Or you can use other text editors like vim and nano they're both working perfectly with Yosemite.

Comment: When trying to save I have a error message : "You do not have the permissions... to edit hosts"

Comment: you need to duplicate the file before editing it with TextEdit and then copy it back

Comment: I think on OS 10.9, it used to work without copying the file. I was looking forward to the same behavior.